# How to know if Unsubscribe channels request in Pubnub is success?

Tags: iphone, swift, push-notification, pubnub

I'm trying to unsubscribe PubNub channels when I logged out  from my app, like this way

```
client?.unsubscribeFromAll()
```

My problem is that I can't be sure that unsubscribe channels process is success or NOT!

there is no completion handler for error, success.

So my question is how can I be sure from unsubscribe channels process?

**EDIT**

I send Push notification in my Pubnub channel, so I want after the user logged out to never get push notification anymore, so I decided to unsubscribe the channel, but it seems that

```
client?.unsubscribeFromAll()
```

doesn't work, because I still get push notification although I logged out from my app, so do you know how to unsubscribe PubNub channel so I won't get push notification after I logged out from my app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To figure this out you should use same callback which is used by delegate to track client state change like this:

```
func client(client: PubNub!, didReceiveStatus status: PNSubscribeStatus!) {

    if status.operation == .UnsubscribeOperation {

        if !status.error { /* Handle successful unsubscription. */ }
        else { /* Handle unsubscription error. */ }
    }
}
```

Callbacks in case of: state change, presence and message arrival used because potentially few observers would like to know about this. Other operation usually context-based and completion block is more than enough in those cases.

**EDIT**
Real-time channels and push notification enabling / disabling - not linked to each other and if explicitly push notifications has been enabled they should be disabled in manually as well. Unsubscription is just disconnection from real-time data channels.

Use code bellow to disable all push notifications for specified `devicePushToken`:

```
client?.removeAllPushNotificationsFromDeviceWithPushToken(devicePushToken, andCompletion: { (status) in

    if !status.error { /* Handle push notification disable completed successfully. */ }
    else { /* Handle push notification disable did fail. */ }
})
```

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: Thanks! 
it can be helpful also in subscribe situation right?

Comment: @Rawan yes, find `UnsubscribeOperation`  definition in header and there you will find other operation types. There also `category` property in `status` object and enum for it in same headers where `UnsubscribeOperation` defined.

Comment: @monlight, thank you sooo mush, 
I've edited my question, so please can take a look? 
thanks, 
Rawan.

Comment: hello, 
can I ask you a question:
client?.unsubscribeFromAll()
what does it do exactly?

Comment: @Rawan if you subscribed on channels and/or channel groups - it will unsubscribe from real-time data streams (you won't receive any updates on channels and groups).

Comment: thanks alot, can I ask another question please? 
how can I clear the channel messages before I logout?

Comment: please check my question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695441/how-to-delete-pubnub-channel-history-when-logout-from-app