# How to delete Pubnub channel history when logout from app?

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

In my App I'm using PubNub channels to read messages.

I get history in two status :

```
 .PNReconnectedCategory
 .PNConnectedCategory
```

I get history like this way:

```
if let lastOpenedDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(PubNubModel.lastHistoryFetchKey) as? NSDate {

        let endDate = NSNumber(double:lastOpenedDate.timeIntervalSince1970)

        if UserHistoryChannel != nil {

            self.client?.historyForChannel(UserHistoryChannel!, start: nil, end: endDate, withCompletion: getHistoryCompletionBlock)
        } 
}
```

**lastOpenedDate** is a last received message date, and

in getting history I always check on it, and getting the history from this date and after it.

on logout I set this date to nil, so when the user login to the App, and Pubnub connect, when getting history this date will be the current date, and there will be no history.

But the pubnub still getting the old history!!

anyone try to clear the pubnub channels history?

Any help pleasssse?

thanks,

Comment: You better to use unique chancel names based on user/device information.

Comment: Somehow, the `endDate` is not getting nil or is getting reset to the time of the last history invocation. But I think you are approaching this in wrong way. You should be storing the publish timetoken of each message locally to the device. When device reconnects, use this last message timetoken to get history (use it as your `endDate` value).

Comment: @CraigConover thanks, but what did you mean by : 
"When device reconnects, use this last message timetoken to get history (use it as your endDate value)"
can you give me more details please ? 
thanks

Comment: @moonlight thanks, but I didn't want to change the channel name, I want when the user sign in again to the app, to subscribe the same channel, maybe I didn't get you :$ 
please If I did, please give me more details. thanks :)

Comment: @Rawan Ah, I missed part about unwanted history. History API allow to specify time frame from which you want to get messages. If you will store time token (`message.data.timetoken`) and use it as `endDate` with history API (as suggested by @CraigConover) - using this setup history will fetch last messages since mentioned date (`endDate`) inclusively (including message from which date has been taken. Using this approach allow not to pull data about which your application and user been aware since last application run. Logged new user's won't get messages (expect one) from previous session.

Answer (score 0):

History API allow to specify time frame from which you want to get messages. If you will store and never reset to `nil` (because it will be treated as last received messages) time token (`message.data.timet‌​oken`) and use it as `endDate` with history API (as suggested by @CraigConover) - using this setup history will fetch last messages since mentioned date (`endDate`) inclusively (including message from which date has been taken. Using this approach allow not to pull data about which your application and user been aware since last application run. Logged new user's won't get messages (expect one) from previous session.